# char to integer value conversion (ord sometimes returns array)

Tags: php, char, integer, chr, ord

is there a function to convert any character to a integer, and then back?
I tried using ord($string) and chr($int), however ord() sometimes returns an array for unusual letters from other languages, such as for "Ü" "Ä" and "Ö" from the german alphabet, is there any way to force it to return a single integer? Or is there an alternative?

Edit: Programming in PHP

Comment: It is not [documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) that ord returns an array. Could you clarify what you mean, possibly with actual code?

Answer (score -1):

You can typecast the string to integer:

```
<?php

$num_string = "100";

$num = (int) $num_string;
```

Comment: I think the idea is to get the integer value of like, the character in some encoding. Basically getting `(int) "a"` then convert back that integer to a character, I don't know.